# "Factum est vesperE et mane"

Tags: declension

Genesim 1:13 Hieronymus sic traduxit:

> Et factum est vesper**e** et mane, dies tertius.

Cur “vespere”, non “vesper”? Puto id in casu nominativo esse debere, sed nonne “vespere” in casu ablativo est? Si non nominativo, subiectum sententiæ quid est?

Answer (score 10):

*Vespere*, like *mane*, is adverbial (originally from the ablative), 'in the evening.' Also like *mane*, in late vulgar Latin it became an indeclinable substantive.

That *mane*, as an ablative, can turn into an adverb and then be used as a noun allows *vespere* to be done on analogy.

For example, Vergil (*Georg*. 3.325) can say *mane novum* 'new morning', Cicero (*Att*. 5.4.1) joked with Atticus about sleeping *mane totum* 'the whole morning', and of course Martial (1.49.36) can simply say, *mane erat* 'it was morning.

While we don't quite see this development with *vesper* in Classical Latin, fifth-century vulgar Latin was no stranger to strange developments, and *mane* furnishes a perfect parallel (both grammatically and conceptually) to allow Jerome to use it as such.

There *is* an alternative way to look at it, which would be to read *factum est* as an impersonal and *vespere et mane* adverbially/as ablatives of time. I don't like that reading, and I think it's being too charitable to vulgar Latin, but there you have it anyway.